# The type or namespace name 'WebHostBuilder' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created empty asp.net core project and I want to set up there angular. For that I need app to serve static files. So my Startup.cs looks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace coreng
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace coreng
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

and there's my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

But it throws an error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line   Suppression State
>       Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebHostBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    coreng..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
>
> C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\coreng\src\coreng\Program.cs   14  Active

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing `aspnet` and `aspnetcore` packages. You're also mixing 1.0 and 1.0RC1 vercions.

Here is a default `project.json` that you can get when creating a asp.net core web project (web api template):

```
//...
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
},
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

Install **Nuget** **Package**: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore

At Solution Explorer.

- Right Click to Dependencies of the project
- Manage Nuget Packages..
- Write "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" to Browse Tab

And install Nuget.